# Minimization of Expected Value

Tags: optimization, expectation, calculus-of-variations

I'd like to know how I can minimize, with respect to $\hat{y}(x)$,
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\mathbb{E}_{p(x,y)}[(\hat{y}(x)-y)^2 + (\hat{y}(x)-y)\Tr(\nabla^2_x\hat{y}(x)) + 
  ||\nabla_x\hat{y}(x)||^2_2],
$$
where $x$ is a vector and $y, \hat{y}(x)$ scalars.

I googled for *functional derivatives* and I read a little about the *Calculus of Variations*. I now know how to minimize functionals of the form
$$
\theta(y(t)) = \int_0^T F(t,y(t),y'(t))dt
$$
by using the *Euler equation*
$$
F_y - \frac{d F_{y'}}{dt} = 0
$$
The problem is that the expression above has a completely different form:
$$
\int_Y\left[\int_X F(\hat{y}(x),\nabla_x\hat y(x),\nabla_x^2\hat y(x))dx\right] dy
$$
We have a gradient, a Hessian and $x$ is a vector!

Is there a general method to minimize functionals like this?

**Note: I found this problem in a book about Deep Learning (see page 216 of [this](http://goodfeli.github.io/dlbook/contents/regularization.html)).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can minimize the functional by computing the ***Gâteaux*** derivative (a generalization of the directional derivative) and equate it to zero.

It's important to note that the derivative must be zero *for every choice of $h(x)$*.
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\theta(\hat y) = \mathbb{E}_{p(x,y)}[(\hat y - y)^2+\nu(\hat y-y)\Tr(\nabla_x^2\hat y) + \nu||\nabla_x\hat y||^2]
$$
$$
d_h\theta(\hat y) = \left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}\theta(\hat y + \alpha h)\right|_{\alpha=0} =
$$
$$
\left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}\mathbb{E}[(\hat y+\alpha h-y)^2 + \nu(\hat y + \alpha h-y)\Tr(\nabla_x^2\hat y + \alpha\nabla_x^2 h) + \nu||\nabla_x\hat y + \alpha\nabla_x h||^2]\right|_{\alpha=0} = 
$$
$$
\left.\mathbb{E}\left[2(\hat y+\alpha h-y)h + \nu\frac{d}{d\alpha}(...)\right]\right|_{\alpha=0} = \mathbb{E}[2(\hat y-y)h + O(\nu)] = 0 \iff
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[(\hat y - y)h + O(\nu)] = 0
$$
Let's rewrite the expectation more explicitly:
$$
\int_X\int_Y p(x,y)((\hat y(x)-y)h(x) + O(\nu))dy dx =
$$
$$
\int_X h(x)\left[\int_Y p(x,y)((\hat y(x)-y) + O(\nu))dy\right]dx = 0 \iff
$$
$$
\int_Y p(x,y)((\hat y(x)-y) + O(\nu))dy = 0
$$
$$
p(x)(\hat y(x) + O(\nu))\int_Y p(y|x)dy = p(x)\int_Y p(y|x)y dy
$$
$$
\hat y(x) + O(\nu) = \mathbb{E}_{p(y|x)}[y]
$$
$$
\hat y(x) = \mathbb{E}_{p(y|x)}[y] + O(\nu)
$$
which is the result in the book.